# Style menu with arch between items

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net, css-selectors

I need to style a menu as shown in the screenshot below. I haven't come up with an efficient way to do it myself. Does anyone have any ideas and could help me out?

[Expected menu layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjo8i.png)

I couldn't come up with an idea how to code this.

Comment: Something like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/r58yajde/1//) (which uses [Unicode Box Drawing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/025.html) lines)? - or can you try to be a bit more specific? Is there some logic involved? The bold tag? A class? What HTML do you have? Can you please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve] of your best try?

Comment: Here's [another, more flexible example](https://jsfiddle.net/ut4wr79h/) that also uses Unicode characters but uses CSS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pseudo element `::before` absolutely positioned inside a relatively positioned LI element. Play with borders and radius:

```css
.list {
  line-height: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  
  >li {
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    
    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      content: "";
      width: 0.6rem;
      border: solid #000;
      border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    &:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;
      border-left: 0;
      
      &::before {
        height: calc(100% - 1.1rem);
        top: 1.1rem;
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
        border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
      }
    }
    
    &:last-child {
      border-left: 0;
      
      &::before {
        height: calc(100% - 1.1rem);
        top: 0rem;
        border-radius: 0 0 0px 10px;
        border-width: 0 0px 1px 1px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <li>Lorem<br>new-line test</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use Unicode's Box drawing lines:

```css
.menu {
  line-height: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  
  >li {
  
    &::before {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
      content: "\2520";
    }
    
    &:first-child::before {
      content: "\256d";
    }
    
    &:last-child::before {
      content: "\2570";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</div>
```

but in that case you cannot have line wraps or other spacing that exceeds line-height of `1`.